# Uniformly cauchy sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, epsilon-delta, cauchy-sequences

A sequence of functions $f_n$ is said to be uniformly cauchy if $$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists N > 0 :\forall z , \forall r, s > N:  |f_r(z) - f_s(z)| < \varepsilon$$

How can I show that if a sequence is uniformly cauchy then $f_n$ converge uniformly to some funciton $f$? We can assume that the metric space is complete.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Here is how to avoid the "let $m \rightarrow \infty$" (see above). Let  $f$ be the pointwise limit (see above). If $\epsilon > 0,$ then so is $\epsilon/2  > 0$ hence there exists a natural number $N_{\epsilon/2}$ such that

$$\forall z, \forall n,m > N_{\epsilon/2}: \left|f_{n}(z)-f_{m}(z)\right|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Let $z$ be arbitrary. If $n > N_{\epsilon/2}$, then we have $$ \left|f(z)-f_{n}(z)\right|\leqslant \left|f(z)-f_{m}(z)\right|+ \left|f_{m}(z)-f_{n}(z)\right|$$ This is true for every $m$. In particular $\left|f(z)-f_{m}(z)\right|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$ if $m>l(z)$, where $l(z)$ is a natural number dependent on $z$, because $f$ is the pointwise limit. Hence, if  $m>\max\left \{N_{\epsilon/2},l(z)\right \}$, we get $$\left|f(z)-f_{n}(z)\right| < \epsilon $$ We have thus shown that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N$, independent of $z$, such that $$\left|f(z)-f_{n}(z)\right| < \epsilon ,\forall n>N,$$ which is exactly what we needed.

Comment: Clearly, you don't understand it, which is rather embarrassing as it is very simple. Obviously $N= N_{\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}}$. It is $m$ which is dependent on $z$ and that does not matter.

Comment: Good that you called me out on my error. I apologize for the wrong accusation. I'll give your answer the deserved upvote.

Comment: Because $l(z)$ is dependent on $z$, you have not found a constant independent of $z$. Thus this does not show uniform convergence

Comment: @DavidHughes our final expression is independent of $m$ so we don't care if $m$ depends on $z$ or not

Comment: I see. Very clever!

Answer (score 4):

Assume that we are given a sequence of functions $f_n:Z\to Y$, and that the metric space $Y$ is complete. According to assumption, for each fixed $z\in Z$ the sequence $\bigl(f_n(z)\bigr)_{n\geq0}$ is a Cauchy sequence in  $Y$. It follows that for each $z\in Y$ the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(z)=: f(z)\in Y$$ exists. I claim that the $f_n$ converge uniformly in $Z$ to the function $f:\>Z\to Y$.

*Proof.* Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then there is an $N\in{\mathbb N}$ such that for all $z\in Z$ we have $$\bigl|f_{n+m}(z)-f_n(z)\bigr|<\epsilon\tag{1}$$ whenever $n>N$ and $m\geq0$. Letting $m\to\infty$ in $(1)$ we conclude that for all $z\in Z$ we have
$$\bigl|f(z)-f_n(z)\bigr|\leq\epsilon\ ,$$
as soon as $n>N$. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitray the claim follows.

Here we have made use of the following **Lemma:** If $a_m\to a\in{\mathbb R}$ $\>(m\to \infty)$ and $a_m\geq 0$ for all $m\geq 1$ then $a\geq 0$.

Comment: thank you for the answer! I've seen more or less this proof on the Rudin, but I am not very fond of the passage "let $m \to \infty$".. It does not seem very rigorous to me! Can you provide an alternative proof (or explain to me why it is indeed okay to take the limit there? )

Answer (score 0):

First, we can show that $f_n$ converges pointwisely to some $f$. Then $\exists N_1$ $|f(z)-f_s(z)|<\epsilon/2 $ $ \forall s>N_1$. (1)

Second, let $\epsilon>0$, $\exists N$ s.t. $\forall z$, we have $|f_s(z) - f_r(z)| < \epsilon/2$. (2)

Now, we want to show that $\forall r>N$ $\forall z$, $|f(z)-f_r(z)|<\epsilon$. Then we are done.

Now choose arbitrary $r>N$, arbitrary $z$.

Using (1), we can find $N_1>N$ s.t. $\forall s>N_1$ and $|f(z)-f_s(z)|<\epsilon/2$. Then $-\epsilon/2+f_s(z) < f(z)<\epsilon/2+f_s(z)$.

Using (2), since $s>N_1>N$ and $r>N$, we can use (2). Then $|f_s(z)-f_r(z)|<\epsilon/2$. Then $-\epsilon/2+f_r(z) < f_s(z) <\epsilon/2+f_r(z)$

Then $|f(z)-f_r(z)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks! But 1) Who is $A$ ? You just mean the norm? and 2) To be fair I'm not really sure on $s \to \infty$.. I mean it makes sense but it's not very rigorous, is it?

Comment: @Ant here the $A$ is the domain of the functions. I introduced it because this is the notation I learnt. Or you can just treat is as the norm (or sup norm) of the funciton. Considering $s \rightarrow \infty$, to be honest, I hate this approach too. Let's see if I can make it more rigorous.

Comment: @Ant I have changed my proof.

Comment: I am not convinced. In particular, your $N_1$ there depends on $z$, *a priori*, because cauchy gives us only pointwise convergence. So all your subsequent inequalities are valid in a single point (or, are valid with a N that depends on $z$.) And this is not what uniform convergence says, is it?

Comment: @Ant, see my new edit. Note that we fix $N$, then fix $x$. Sorry if I didn't write it clearly yesterday for being sick.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but it's really messy and it's becoming difficult to follow your argument. Could you polish it up a little? I didn't fully understand what your wrote in the new edit, but the point is that you *can't* fix $N$ and then fix $x$; that would mean that $N$ depends only on $\varepsilon$, which is indeed what you need to show. A priori (for the "limit function" $f$) we have that $N$ depends on both $\epsilon$ and $x$

Comment: @Ant why do you think that the $N$ depends on $x$?

Comment: Referring to the proof before the edit, $N_1$ depends on $x$ because $f$ is the pointwise limit. If $N_1$ didn't depend on $x$ we would have uniform convergence but that is what we are trying to prove.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23919/discussion-between-k99731-and-ant).